# I need to know if this is a virus

Tags: virus

Someone has been sending me these weird emails and I am starting to get curious about it.
The latest one has an image of a broken image linking to this address...
I wonder if you guys could help me figure it out.

storage.googleapis.com/baleiao/Intimacao.zip

Comment: How should this be a virus?

Comment: If you're gonna download, unpack and run files off the internet that were linked in weird emails from people that you don't trust and they offered no explanation for it, then it's not viruses you have to worry about. There's nothing to answer here, we're not a virus scanning service.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think anyone is going to that link, download it, unzip it, run it and verify whether it is virus or not. If you got antivirus software like Kaspersky installed in your computer, probably it will deny saving it in your PC if it is a virus. Alternatively, you can check out online scanner (http://www.virscan.org/) if you have already downloaded the file.

Answer (score 1):

I've downloaded the file and this image has appeared when I turned on outlook on chrome first time (I am on a Brazilian computer, so that explains the Portuguese Language; point your mouse on the image to see the translation):

[image: The translation is: "More privacy, less threat. Internet Explorer has advanced resources of privacy and safety to help on protecting you on Web and Outlook.com"]

So it will really do something on your computer if you download and use it.

Comment: I hope you did this on machine you were going to wipe and reinstall anyway or at least in a VM.

Comment: Muito Obrigado, I am on a Brazilian computer as well and figured you guys here would have better set up to deal with it.